# How to use an if statement in a lambda function in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I am new in C#, I am not quite understand lambda, I want to convert this code to lambda expression

```cs
private static bool my_method(int i)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to convert this code to lambda expression, Thank

Comment: Assuming you mean as part of LINQ: `.Select(v => v == 0)` or `.Where(v => v== 0)`?

Comment: What makes you think you need a lambda expression here?

Comment: This code isn't valid C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code, made legal with a function name, looks like this:

```
private static bool SomeFunction(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That can get rewritten as this:

```
private static bool SomeFunction(int i)
{
    return i == 0;
}
```

Which can, in turn, be rewritten as this:

```
private static bool SomeFunction(int i) => i == 0;
```

And that, can get rewritten, as a `Func<int, bool>` lambda, as this:

```
Func<int, bool> someFunction = i => i == 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

There already is an answer to this but I want to include more details.

If you have a function such as

```cs
bool MyMethod(int i)
{
    ...//Method body
}
```

and you want to change it as a lambda expression, you can make use of the `Func<ReturnType, Parmeter1, Parameter2, ...>` delegate with `MyMethod()` defined before as:

```
using System;

Func<int, bool> myLabmdaExp = (i) => MyMethod(i); //Here it is implied that i is an int
```

or you could define the expression in braces `{}` such as:

```cs
using System;

Func<int, bool> myLabmdaExp = (i) => 
{
    ....//Function body
}
```

In your case,

```cs
Func<int, bool> func = (val) =>
{
    if(i==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

You can use a bit of boolean logic to reduce your lamda expression as

```cs
Func<int, bool> func = (val) => val==0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Func<int, bool> func = (i) => {
    if (i == 0) return true;
    else return false;
};
```

Comment: While correct, this is awful.